# Jupyter Notebook graph has very inaccurate scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

this is my first post and I hope it's okay. My mentor gave me a [use case](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/05/21/introduction-machine-learning-jupyter-notebooks#using_a_jupyter_notebook_for_machine_learning) he found online to teach me machine learning on Jupyter. I had a problem with the graphing section, even though I'm sure the code in that part is accurate:

```
df21.plot(figsize=(20,10), fontsize=12,subplots=True, style=["-","o"], title = "Pump 2 - 100 Values")
plt.show()
```

The graphs seems to appear as two points or a single straight line, even though the df21 dataset I'm using has 100 lines, and the values are not binary:

[Graphs just look like straight lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu7hv.png)

[Screenshot of the use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0P6o.png)

I tried changing format to just plots and found that the points are actually all there, the scale of the axes is just incredibly squished:

[Graph with only plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkaCx.png)

And I have no idea what to do now, and I haven't been able to find any solutions online. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this as not reproducible. With the data and code from you're link, this works without issue. [Code and Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I73X.png)

Comment: Having toy data that could help us reproduce your problem would help resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

After going through the [use case](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/05/21/introduction-machine-learning-jupyter-notebooks#using_a_jupyter_notebook_for_machine_learning) you added and trying the code myself i did not find any problem with the plot section. probably there is a problem with you parts before plotting. This is the code from the [use case](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/05/21/introduction-machine-learning-jupyter-notebooks#using_a_jupyter_notebook_for_machine_learning):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sa-mw-dach/manuela-dev/master/ml-models/anomaly-detection/raw-data.csv')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'], unit='ms')
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['ts'], inplace=True)

df21 = df.head(200)
df21.plot(figsize=(20,10), fontsize=12, subplots=True, style=["-","o"], title = "Pump 2 - 100 Values")
plt.show()
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Maybe try a different environment to run your notebook i tried running it on google colab.